# Cassandra client can't connect immediately after Cassandra startup

Tags: cassandra

We have unclustered, single-node Cassandra 3.11.2 instances supporting many separate customer environments. Recently, we have seen many cases where a Cassandra instance is started successfully by a client script, but unable to connect with that client immediately because of a 'connection refused' error. Here is an excerpt from the client-side log showing the startup messages and connect error.  The client is using the Java driver version 3.0.1.

```
2023-08-11 00:21:39,669 DEBUG [main:2cb1] STDOUT - 00:21:39.668 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Starting new cluster with contact points [<host>:18512]
...
2023-08-11 00:21:39,915 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-0:2cb1] STDOUT - 00:21:39.915 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[<host>, inFlight=0, closed=false] Error connecting to <host>:18512 (Connection refused: <host>:18512)
2023-08-11 00:21:39,920 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-0:2cb1] STDOUT - 00:21:39.920 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Host.STATES - Defuncting Connection[<host>:18512-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] because: [<host>] Cannot connect
2023-08-11 00:21:39,921 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-0:2cb1] STDOUT - 00:21:39.921 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Host.STATES - [<host>:18512] preventing new connections for the next 1000 ms
2023-08-11 00:21:39,921 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-0:2cb1] STDOUT - 00:21:39.921 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Host.STATES - [<host>:18512] Connection[<host>:18512-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] failed, remaining = 0
2023-08-11 00:21:39,922 DEBUG [cluster1-nio-worker-0:2cb1] STDOUT - 00:21:39.921 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[<host>:18512-1, inFlight=0, closed=true] closing connection
2023-08-11 00:21:39,931 DEBUG [main:2cb1] STDOUT - 00:21:39.931 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] error on <host>:18512 connection, no more host to try
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [<host>] Cannot connect
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:158) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:141) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:603) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:563) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:424) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:276) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:292) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: <host>:18512
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

The startup and connection had been working OK for a long time before this, but we found that the error was triggered by a change in the resolution sequence of several DNS servers used to locate the Cassandra node.  One DNS server responds about 0.2 ms faster than the other, and when the slower one is first in the sequence the error is raised.  It seems to be a delicate timing issue.  We don't see any errors in the server-side system.log or debug.log.

My questions are:

1. Should such a small difference in DNS resolution times really cause the Cassandra connection to fail, or is something else going on?  We don't want the Cassandra connection to depend on DNS server sequencing.
2. In the 3.0.1 driver, I see the RetryPolicy and ReconnectionPolicy classes and how custom implementations can change their behavior.  However, after reading the driver code, I don't think any of these options will affect the initial connection to Cassandra, only downstream recovery scenarios when queries fail or connections are lost.  Is this the case, or would any of these options actually help?
3. I see that the newer 4.13.0 driver has more configuration options in this area, including an **advanced.reconnect-on-init** property that looks relevant.  Would upgrading the driver and setting this property address the issue?

Any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: worth noting that `3.11.2` is close to 6 years old release. [`3.11.16` is the latest version as of this writing that got released on 20-Aug-2023](https://lists.apache.org/thread/7w2gkgf04v225tsf4s3zf3b49yh7jmrq) and [`4.1.3` is the latest which got released on 24-Jul-2023](https://lists.apache.org/thread/go84k4vxjhnb5nodmk7omwrtjxm17rxk). Also, `We have unclustered, single-node Cassandra 3.11.2 instances supporting many separate customer environments` is not clearly defined and I can't understand how it is faster than other node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like you're running into a race condition where your app is trying to connect to the Cassandra instance before it has fully started.

In the stack trace you posted, it clearly shows that the Java driver is not able to establish a control connection to the cluster because the Cassandra instance is not online yet.

The `Connection refused` message in the exception indicates that there is no process on the host listening for connections. During the startup process, the last step for Cassandra is to start listening for clients on the CQL port when it is ready. Until the initialisation process has completed, Cassandra will not be ready to accept requests so your app needs to wait.

I don't believe upgrading is going to solve the problem since it's not a driver issue. Cheers!